# Core Animation profiling: When an app is idle, should it be 0fps of 60fps?

Tags: ios, xcode, core-animation, instruments

I've been trying to optimize scrolling of my UICollectionView, and the Core Animation profiler has me puzzled...

When the app is idle (no scrolling or interaction in anyway) I'm averaging around 59-60 fps, but occasionally it will drop down to 7 or 12 fps:

[image]

Is this expected behavior? Because I'm not interacting with the app when this drop happens I don't visually see anything, but I'm curious if this is something I should be troubleshooting.

Other times when profiling core animation bottlenecks I've seen fps drop down to 0 fps when idle/not interacting with the app.

The app isn't crash or freezing, so is this some sort of bug in Instruments? (I'd expect consistently to be 0fps or close to 60fps when nothing is happening in the app).

**Update:**

Here's an example of the FPS graph after running the profiler a few minutes later (I'd tried turning on rasterization for a type of view, but then reverted back to not rasterizing, so although the project was rebuilt, the codebase is the same):

[image]

Here I'm getting between 32 and 55 fps when interacting with the app, and dropping down to 0 fps when idle.

From my subjective perspective I'm not noticing anything major between what I'm seeing between these two examples, but from Xcode's perspective I'm seeing two different stories.

Does anyone know what's happening here?